# Javascript forms changing what a canvas draws

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a interactive model of the human circulatory and lymphatic systems for my biology class. I decided to use a HTML5 canvas and Javascript to make it work, with checkboxes indicating which organs to be shown. For some reason though, the form data doesn't change in my script. Here are the snippets:

HTML5:

```
...SNIP...
<form id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label>Body </label> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label> Heart </label> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label> Subclavian Veins </label> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label> Spleen </label> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label> Thymus </label> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label> Veins </label> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label> Arteries </label> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label> Lymphatic Vessels </label> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> <label> Lymphatic Nodes </label> <br/> <br/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="return change()"> Change! </button>
</form>
...SNIP...
```

Javascript:

```
...SNIP...
var draws = new Array(9);
for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    draws[i] = true;
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.scale(4, 4);
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        if(draws[i]) sprites[i].render();
    }
    ctx.scale(0.25, 0.25);
}
setInterval(draw, 16.6);

function change(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        draws[i] = document.getElementById("form").elements[i].value == "on";
    }
    return false;
}
...SNIP...
```

Here is an image demonstrating the problem (You can see that the checkboxes have been unchecked and the button has been clicked, but the body and heart are still being drawn...):

[image]

Comment: You need an onValueChanged listener on the checkboxes. Inside that listener, you can then redraw the image.

Comment: @glen-piece, could you provide an example or some documentation. I can't seem to find what you're talking about specifically.

Comment: **"name censored"** You are aware that your name is also showing in the browser address bar right?

Comment: No need for that language. I noticed you felt the need to "name censor" so I thought I would just let you know that your name is still being displayed in the image.... so you could maybe edit it if you wanted to keep your name censored. Good luck getting help with that attitude, you can do your own homework young man!

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="change()"` not `onclick="return change()"` I'm not certain that this matters, but it's good practice.

Then don't forget to call `draw()` again in `change()`. You aren't redrawing the image otherwise.

```
function change(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        draws[i] = document.getElementById("form").elements[i].value == "on";
    }
    draw(); //this is important
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Adding `draw()` to `change()` doesn't fix it. I don't think that this is the problem since it draw is being called every 16.66 milliseconds anyways.